# (Racket) Interpreting Seq to return last expression in list

Tags: racket

I have an ExprC language with multiple variants, and I want to be able to interpret the seqC variant. The seqC variant returns the last expression in the list of expressions given.

```
(define-type ExprC
  [numC (n : number)]
  [idC (s : symbol)]
  [plusC (left : ExprC) (right : ExprC)]
  [multC (left : ExprC) (right : ExprC)]
  [letC (id : symbol) (value : ExprC) (expr : ExprC)]
  [appC (func : ExprC) (arg : ExprC)]
  [lamC (param : symbol) (body : ExprC)]
  [boxC (val : ExprC)]
  [unboxC (bx : ExprC)]
  [setboxC (bx : ExprC) (val : ExprC)]
  [seqC (e : (listof ExprC)]
  )
```

Currently, I'm able to get it to interpret basic sequences such as:

```
(test (interp (seqC (list (numC 1) (numC 2) (numC 3))) mt-env mt-store)
        (v*s (numV 3) mt-store))
```

However, when I try more complicated sequences, such as this one that is constantly setting the value of a box "x":

```
(test (interp {letC 'x {boxC {numC 1}} {seqC {list {setboxC {idC 'x}
                                                         {plusC {numC 2}
                                                                {unboxC {idC 'x}}}}
                                                {setboxC {idC 'x}
                                                         {multC {numC 4}
                                                                {unboxC {idC 'x}}}}
                                                {setboxC {idC 'x}
                                                         {plusC {numC 1}
                                                                {unboxC {idC 'x}}}}
                                                {unboxC {idC 'x}}}}} mt-env mt-store)
        (v*s (numV 13) (mem 2 (list (cell 1 (numV 13))
                                     (cell 1 (numV 12))
                                     (cell 1 (numV 3))
                                     (cell 2 (boxV 1))
                                     (cell 1 (numV 1))))))
```

It's only evaluating the first expression and returning that value, rather than doing each set/unbox and returning the final value. Error statement:

```
    (bad (interp (letC 'x (boxC (numC 1)) 
(seqC (list (setboxC (idC 'x) (plusC (numC 2) (unboxC (idC 'x)))) 
(setboxC (idC 'x) (multC (numC 4) (unboxC (idC 'x)))) 
(setboxC (idC 'x) (plusC (numC 1) (unboxC (idC 'x)))) 
(unboxC (idC 'x))))) mt-env mt-store) 
//Value the interpreter is getting
(v*s (numV 3) (mem 2 (list (cell 1 (numV 3)) (cell 2 (boxV 1)) (cell 1 (numV 1))))) 
//Value it should be
(v*s (numV 13) (mem 2 (list (cell 1 (numV 13)) (cell 1 (numV 12)) 
(cell 1 (numV 3)) (cell 2 (boxV 1)) (cell 1 (numV 1)))))
```

My interpreter for seqC is as follows:

```
(define (interp [expr : ExprC] [env : Env] [sto : Store]) : Result
  (type-case ExprC expr
...
[seqC (m) (type-case Result (interp (firstE m) env sto)
                     [v*s (first-v first-s)
                          (cond
                            [(empty? (rest m)) ;no more left to be sequenced
                             (v*s first-v first-s)]
                            [(not (empty? (rest m))) ;not empty
                             (interp (lastE m) env first-s)])])] ;call function on next item in list
```

firstE and lastE is just a basic helper function that returns the first or last expression in a given list of ExprC's. If you need anymore information to understand the code, just let me know and I can provide it/explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't match your comment. You say that you want to "call function on next item in list", but your code just interprets the last element directly, skipping (middle) elements in `m` which is obviously wrong.

If you think recursively, you will see that there's no need for `lastE` at all. In each step of recursion, you interprets the first element in the sequence. If `(rest m)` is empty, then cool, you just return the value. Otherwise, you can construct a `seqC` which contains `(rest m)` and interprets it (with the new store).